# Automation Error When Inserting Building Blocks programatically Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

### What I am trying to do

I have a template I am trying to build. Within this template I am trying to have a button from which I can dynamically add sections (Note template is in design mode). (See image below)

[image]

Also within this template as shown in the image above I have a rich text content control for which will be used as a parent content control to nest repeating content controls with the contained fields (to be expanded on later). The repeating content control will be inserted by calling a custom building block which I will describe below.

### Making the Building Block

1. First I select the repeating content control made by using the developer tab in the template. I name this content control and give it a title(inspector) and a tag I also set the show as value to None.

[image]

2. Then I run my procedure in vba which takes the range from the selection and creates a custom building block in the attached template. The template is then saved. The code is as follows

   ```
   Public Sub mybookmark()
    Dim objTemplate As Template
    Dim selectionRange As Range
    Dim objBB As BuildingBlock
    Set selectionRange = Selection.Range
    Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
    Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Add("Inspector", _ 
    wdTypeCustom1,"Inspector", selectionRange)
    objTemplate.Save
    Debug.Print objTemplate.Saved
   End Sub
   ```

### Using the Building Block

Once the building block is made I can then use it to make new field lines whenever the button is pressed to which the code is the following

```
Public Sub insertmybookmark()
  Dim objTemplate As Template: Set objTemplate = 
  ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
  Dim objBB As BuildingBlock: Set objBB = 
  objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom1). _
  Categories("Inspector").BuildingBlocks("Inspector")
  Dim myrange As Range: Set myrange = 
  ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("InspectorNames"). _ 
  Item(1).Range
  myrange.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
  Dim mycount As Integer: mycount = 
  ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Inspector").Count
  objBB.Insert myrange
End Sub
```

Running this code twice yeilds

[image]

[image]

### The Problem

When saving and closing the document then opening it again, the insert code works once and then raises the following error

[image]

When I looked up this error it was called an automation error. However, I do not understand how this can work once and then not work again. I could simply get around this by making a global variable to be initialized with the building block the first time the code is run but I would like to understand the root of this problem.

Note: I have tried to structure this as best as possible, if anything is unclear please let me know.

Comment: Click on "Debug", so that you go to your code. In the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) type: `myRange.Select`. Switch back to the document window and look where the Selection is. Try to insert the Building Block as an end-user. Can you? Do you get a more informative error message? Test moving the Selection until you are able to insert.

Comment: @Cindy I get an error saying this document has to many unsaved changes. When looking online I can't find any  helpful resources explaining this error. Thank you for inserting the pictures for me btw really appreciate it !

Comment: And if you Save or SaveAs, then try again?

Comment: Same error. Its very odd. I really don't understand whats going on. It only works when the building block is made that particular session

Comment: Did you check the current Selection, as I suggested in my first comment? When you get errors of this nature it often turns out that the specified Range/Selection is unable to "hold" what you're trying to put there.